# Solving a system of linear congruences

Tags: number-theory

> Find all positive integer solutions to \begin{align*}x &\equiv -1 \pmod{n} \\ x&\equiv 1 \pmod{n-1}. \end{align*}

I rewrote the system as $x = nk_1-1$ and $x = (n-1)k_2+1$. Thus, we have $nk_1-1 = (n-1)k_2+1$ and so $n(k_1-k_2) = 2-k_2 \implies n = \frac{2-k_2}{k_1-k_2}$. How do I solve it from here?

Comment: for a fixed $n$ or fixed $x$?

Answer (score 6):

As $n,n-1$ are relatively prime the Chinese Remainder Theorem guarantees a unique solution $\pmod {n(n-1)}$ .  Indeed we have, $$x\equiv 2n-1 \pmod {n(n-1)}$$

To see this, solve the first congruence to get $x=-1+mn$.  Substituting that into the second gives $$-1+mn\equiv 1 \pmod {n-1}\implies mn\equiv 2 \pmod {n-1}\implies m\equiv 2 \pmod {n-1}$$

And we are done.

Comment: Is $n = 2$ the only solution?

Comment: Not at all.  The general form works for any $n$.  If $n=7$, say, the solution you want is $x\equiv 13 \pmod {42}$.

Comment: @Puzzled417 Are you trying to solve for $x$ or for $n$?

Comment: @LeviathanTheEsper  To clarify:  I assumed that $n$ was given and I then solved for $x$.  I agree the problem is vaguely worded, so perhaps something else was intended.  But my general form shows that for any $n\in \mathbb N$ there is a viable $x$, unique $\pmod {n(n-1)}$.

Comment: Yes. That is how I interpreted the problem too.

@Puzzled417
The Chinese Remainder Theorem guarantees a solution modulo the product of the moduli whenever the moduli are pairwise coprime. In this case $n$ and $n-1$ are always coprime so there is a solution for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

First note that $x_0=2n-1$ is a solution.

Now, if $x$ is a solution, then $x\equiv x_0\pmod n$ and $x\equiv x_0\pmod {n-1}$. Thus, $n|x-x_0$ and $(n-1)|x-x_0$. Also, since $\gcd(n,n-1)=1$, we have $n(n-1)|x-x_0$.

Moreover, for all non-negative integer $k$, we can check that $x=2n-1+kn(n-1)$ is a solution.

Thus, all solutions are $x=2n-1+kn(n-1)$, where $k\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0}$.

Answer (score 1):

The two congruences are equivalent to $$\begin{cases}x=nu-1\\x=(n-1)v+1\end{cases}$$
It follows the diophantine equation $$nu-(n-1)v=2$$ which admits the particular solution $(u,v)=(2,2)$ hence the general solution is  $$\begin{cases}u=(n-1)t+2\\v=nt+2\end{cases}$$ Finally one has
$$x=n((n-1)t+2)-1$$ where $t$ is an arbitrary integer.

(*The first congruence is clearly verified; the second gives $x\equiv 2n-1\equiv 1\pmod{n-1}$ because of $2n-1=2(n-1)+1$*)